# Static electricity with calcium carbonate particles

Tags: electrostatic-energy

We are working with small calcium carbonate particles (microfossils) but one of the problems is they stick to the plastic or metal tools we are using, presumably due to static charge. For example, small particles on plastic tray will stick to the surface even if it is upside down.

- I'm guessing the static potential is related to how much calcium carbonate wants to gain or give away electronics?
- What is this called in this context?
- How do I choose a material that has a low potential for static electricity (i.e. sticking) with calcium carbonate particles?

Answer (score -1):

Some links of a commercial equipment to avoid problems of static electricity in powders during weighing:

https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/products/Laboratory_Weighing_Solutions/Accessories/anti_static_devices.html

http://lab.mt.com/antistatic/

https://www.mt.com/dam/mt_ext_files/Editorial/Generic/6/Anti-static_0x000246700004f0770006d93b_files/ion_e.pdf

Comment: Hi, answers that contain barely more than links are discouraged, and might get removed.

Comment: Markos, can you explain how these products will help and simply use the links as a way to access further information.  Also, if you are affiliated with the company, please disclose that.

Comment: My intention was to help by giving some reference.                                  I received a flyer of this company some time ago and I remembered about this product when I read the question.
I also had this type of problem in laboratory when weighing organic fine powders (pigments).
I don't work for this company so I don't know the working principle of this device.
I suggest to ask the manufacturer or other supplier about about the operating principle of the equipment.